# Touble with make an array from string

Tags: php

I want to make an array for Dropdown From this string so can you help to make an array?

String:

```
---Tafadhali chagua---
Mwanafunzi
Muajiriwa
Nimejiajiri
Sina kazi
Nyinginezo
```

Attempt:

```
$pizza = "---Tafadhali chagua--- Mwanafunzi Muajiriwa Nimejiajiri Sina kazi Nyinginezo";
$pieces = explode("/n", $pizza);
print_r($pieces);
```

Comment: yes i tried but it's not worked

Comment: $pizza  = "---Tafadhali chagua---
Mwanafunzi
Muajiriwa
Nimejiajiri
Sina kazi
Nyinginezo";
$pieces = explode("/n", $pizza);
print_r($pieces);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/n` is not a new line, it is a forward slash and an `n`. A backslash and an `n` make a new line, better yet is to use the PHP constant [`PHP_EOL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol) (for end of line).

```
$string = '---Tafadhali chagua---
Mwanafunzi
Muajiriwa
Nimejiajiri
Sina kazi
Nyinginezo';
print_r(explode(PHP_EOL, $string));
```

https://3v4l.org/00nN2